# How could I turn coordinates x,y,z coordinates of several objects into an Android app that displays the position of these objects?

Tags: java, android, 3d, coordinates

I am using eclipse with the adk android plugin and I am completely lost

Comment: What is "completely lost"? Do you know how to create any kind of Android app at all?

Comment: I've created an app that can print the values of the coordinates but I'm lost as to how I'd translate these coordinate values into some kind of graphic.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on what do you mean by displaying their location:

1. Relative to each other on a blank screen.
   Read up on distance calculation in coordinates and draw the locations relative to their distance from each other.
2. On a map, each one separately from the other or together.
   Use a web/binary API for map display like Google Maps (don't want to spam and post links with my reputation), or write your app to display Open map data from sources like OpenStreetMap.
3. On a satellite/aerial images.
   Pretty much the same as #3 just you have less options to investigate and try.

If you were a bit clearer in your question, I could have been more specific with the answers, if you edit your question and clarify more, I could be more specific.